# problems updating system: update manager says newest update is 11.10

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, release-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install software or upgrade from old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-old-unsupported-release)

When I open my update manager I get a window saying:

Your Ubuntu release is not supported anymore.

You will not get any further security fixes or critical updates. Please upgrade to a later version of Ubuntu Linux

when I close the window it says the newest upgrade is ubuntu 11.10.

When I'd like to run it it says error...?

what to do?

thanks!

Comment: have you tried opening the terminal with Ctrl-Alt+T and forcing it to upgrade with sudo update-manager -d? Maybe that will work